# How to Log Out Using Access Token in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to log out by using access token that was returned during log in.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { Drawer,Container, Content, Header, Right, Button } from 'native-base';
import { FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons'; 


export default class SideBar extends React.Component {
render() {
    //console.log(this.props.usertoken);
    return (
        <Container>
            <Header>
            <Right>
                <Button transparent>
                    <FontAwesome  name="close" size={24} color="#FFFFFF" onPress={() => this.props.closeDrawer()} />
                </Button>   
            </Right>
            </Header>
            <Content>
            
            <Button transparent onPress={() => Alert.alert('Log Out Button pressed')}>
                <Text style={{fontSize: 24}}>Log Out</Text>       
            </Button>  
            </Content>
        </Container>
    );
    }
    }
```

I have retrieved the access token in this page by "this.props.usertoken"...can anyone help me about how to logout by binding that access token to Log Out button.

Answer (score 0):

Create a global state using Context API or use redux to store user data globally and access the user data like token and other things to process it.

checkout more about the global state:

- Context API
  https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/01/introduction-react-context-api/
- React Redux
  https://react-redux.js.org/

Use Async storage or redux persist for storing the data to the app data it accesses after the restart of the application.

- Async Storage
  https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/api/
- Redux Persist
  https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist

Answer (score 0):

In case if you need any help regarding the local async storage you can have a look at this code.

https://github.com/PiyushGaurav/devkraft-task

It is basically an app with sign in, sign up and home screen. You can have a look at how the Async storage is used at the sign in, sign up, and logout function. Also, check how the app checks for the current logged user data from local storage.